# MVC 4 ApiController not serializing System.Json.JsonObject properly

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am new to working with MVC4 and the serialization of objects on the back end seems pretty "magical" to me so if I am doing this the wrong way please let me know.

My goal however is to build a simple rest API and return JSON out.  I figured that I would use System.Json and just return JsonObject.  I have simplified this down for the sake of this question but the objects are much more complicated in my real issue.

Here is my controller....

```
....

 public class ActionsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/actions
        public JsonObject Get()
        {
            JsonObject testObjet = new JsonObject();
            testObjet.Add("Name", "Test name");
            testObjet.Add("Description", "Test Description");

            return testObjet;

        }
....
```

I would expect to see:

```
{"Name":"Test name","Description":"Test Description"}
```

Instead I see:

```
{"Name":[],"Description":[]}
```

I actually seem to get better results when I return a string of the JsonObject or heck even just return the object itself with the exception it has enums and I want to return the names not the number values, which is what led me to JsonObject for customization.

Does anyone know why it is dropping off the values?

EDIT:
So because of Dan's comments below I tried just for giggles to see what the XML serializer spit out with the JSON object and I get the below exception...

"Type 'System.Json.JsonPrimitive' with data contract name 'JsonPrimitive:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Json' is not expected."

So it appears that you can not serialize the System.Json.JsonObject object, because it uses a type that it does not expect.

That is shocking.  Does anyone have a workaround?  If not I am off to find out how to show enum names when serializing instead of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is apparently... You Can't!

It appears that the type JsonPrimitive is not supported to serialize objects.  The answers provided below by Obi and Dan helped me to poke around a bit more and find out that the XML serializer actually throws an exception while the JSON serializer simply eats it and puts out an empty array which is what you see above.

There are any number of correct answers here.

1. Make your own custom serializer
2. Output JSON as a string
3. Return custom objects and then work around things like the Enum
   values

I am sure there are others.

But whatever you do don't try to use System.Json as a return in the ApiController because you will get the results above.

Answer (score 0):

You should not force your WebApi call to use a particular format like JSON.  One of the features of WebApi is that you can specify the format as part of the request.  Return an object from your `Get` call, and let the WebApi engine do the serialization and deserialization:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ActionsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/actions
    public DataObject Get()
    {
        var testObject = new DataObject
        {
            Name = "Test name",
            Description = "Test Description"
        };

        return testObject;
    }
}
```

You can specify the format by setting the `Accept` header to `application/xml`, `application/json`, etc.

The default JSON serializer has no problem serializing simple string properties like `Name` and `Description`.

Comment: Ok that's great and all thanks for the tip but it still isn't serializing the values properly which is the issue.

Comment: Well I think there must be something else going on here.  I use the technique above all the time, and it works fine.  The serialized JSON that you posted seems like it would be the result of `Name` and `Description` being null.  Can you confirm that is not the case?

Comment: Yeah matter of fact the expected example was me inspecting the object in the debugger and pasting the value of it in here.  The funny thing is I tried it in XML because of your comment and it throws an exception "type 'System.Json.JsonPrimitive' with data contract name 'JsonPrimitive:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Json' is not expected."

Comment: So you are saying if you cut and paste that and then return it you don't get the type not expected using System.Json?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27787/discussion-between-dan-and-roloc)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you did this instead

<del>// GET api/actions
        public object Get()
        {
            //New up a strongly typed object if you want to return a specific type
            //and change Action return type accordingly
            var testObjet = new (){
                             Name= "Test name",
                             Description= "Test Description"
                             };

            return testObjet;


        }</del>

Dan has posted a similar answer below so let me try to address your other problem. To serialize the enum, I would suggest you hide it in a public string property which would return the string value of the enum,

```
public class DataObject{
    public MyEnum SomeEnumValue;
    public string EnumValue{
       get {
          //..return SomeEnumValue string value
        }
    }
}
```

You can then read the value from EnumValue which should be properly serialized as you want.

Comment: So is the answer here simply System.Json.JsonObject can not be serialized properly?  But these generic objects can?  Is there someplace you can override the serializer?

Comment: @Roloc, I guess your initial post was misread. With WebApi, you would usually be serving up a resource and therefore it is more advisable to return the resource. I doubt that JsonObject is your resource.

Comment: Well it's not, but shouldn't it be able to be?  I mean, does that not seem silly that a Json Serializer can't serialize a Json object?

Comment: Yes and it is, however it may not serialize exactly as you need your own custom resource to be. Take a look at the public properties of JsonObject to see how it deserializes.

Comment: Turns out it doesn't serialize at all, it throws an exception which gets eaten somewhere in the JSON Serializer but not in the XML one... wacky.

Comment: Not surprised! I guess your best bet would be to return your resource object. There's loads of tutorials, let's know if the solution I gave you helps you serialize the enum